# To Push new object to table component

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6

I have an `api` called `customers`,inside this i have `id's` of the other `api` called `workers` based on this `id's` i am displaying `workers of the particular customer` in the `table` like this:
[image]

When i hit the `edit` button, it will display the same `workers` in  an dialog component called `edit`. Where it will display the `same workers` in the `table` like this:

[image]

Here for the workers(table) **i am checking the duplicates and pushing the more workers** from the `dropdown` as shown in above image, this `dropdown` is an another component called `workers-list`

In `edit` component i have an `form` to generate a **new customer**, Where i will generate a new customer and i am pushing that generated new customer to the `workers` table.

[image]

> Now the issue is i am able to push this new customer to the table, I can **log** and see that it has been pushed to the table, but it is not reflecting in the table.

**[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/loading-object-properties-into-table-by-other-component-w1qsqp?file=src/app/edit/edit.component.ts)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to create a separate class to maintan the datasource. lets call it `DataSourceItem`

```
export class DataSourceItems extends DataSource<any> {

  constructor(private items) {
    super();
  }

  connect(): Observable<any> {
    return of(this.items);
  }

  disconnect() {
    // No-op
  }

}
```

Now once you update the array object. create a instance of this class to datasource

```
public onAdd(): void {
    this.addeNewWorker = this.addWorkerForm.value; 
    this.addeNewWorker.id = '05';
      this.customerWorkers.push(this.addeNewWorker);
      console.log(this.customerWorkers); // Since it won't geenrate a new ID so iam harcoding the ID
      this.customerWorkers = new DataSourceItems(this.customerWorkers);  
    }

}
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/loading-object-properties-into-table-by-other-component-ts9sol?file=src/app/edit/edit.component.ts)

Answer (score 1):

Please add following code at end of onAdd method.

```
if (this.customerWorkers.items) {
  this.customerWorkers.items.push(this.addeNewWorker);
  this.customerWorkers = new DataSourceItems(this.customerWorkers.items);
}
else {
  this.customerWorkers.push(this.addeNewWorker);
  this.customerWorkers = new DataSourceItems(this.customerWorkers);
}
```